# Using dired via tramp on a remote machine

Tags: dired, tramp

Maybe I am missing something rather simple but I completely fail to use `dired` on a remote machine. I can connect via `ssh` directly without emacs and I can edited a file using Tramp on the remote machine from within Emacs, as it should be. But when I want to use `dired` to show the home directory on the remote machine I just get an buffer with just one line but not the files in this directory.

I did

```
C-x C-f /ssh:martin@martins-mbp.fritz.box:/Users/Martin/
```

and was expecting that the whole directory is shown as it is on my local machine.

During completion, i.e. before I press `Enter` above, I see the files and directories on my remote machine.

Any hint is gratefully acknowledge.

**EDIT**

Just to document my findings: I disabled `dired-quicksort` and switched back to macOS' `ls` and it works fine now. I do not have the time to investigate this further but maybe this will help others in the future.

Comment: Failing anything else, what happens if you edit a file in the directory of interest, and then use `M-x dired` and accept the default directory at the prompt?

Comment: @phils That was just a Copy-and-Paste error, sorry

Comment: If I edit a file and then do 'M-x dired' as suggested I see the same result.

Comment: I just checked using `emacs -Q`and it works as expected. There must be something in my config breaking `dired`. I will document my findings here.

Comment: I am not completely sure but it looks like some issue with using `dired-quicksort` and/or gnu ls on macOS. I switched back to the original `ls` for `insert-directory-program` and deactivating `dired-quicksort` and it works fine.

Comment: OP: Thanks for following up your investigation. Maybe include such information in the question (if you don't find the answer by investigating) or in an answer that you provide. That will likely help others.

Comment: Hi Martin, the latest version of `dired-quick-sort` should have resolved BSD ls issue (it will disable itself if `ls` is non-GNU). I'm still working on Tramp support, so hopefully this issue would be gone soon: https://gitlab.com/xuhdev/dired-quick-sort/-/issues/9

Comment: Thanks! Good to know

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and it was caused by the fact that one of the `ls` switches I use normally in dired was not working on the server shell.
Removing all the switches except `-l` with `C-u s` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use dired instead of find-file, this command should invoke tramp to use dired

`C-x C-d /ssh:martin@martins-mbp.fritz.box:/Users/Martin/`